# Gnome Shell doesn't recognize Wine windows

Tags: gnome, wine, gnome-shell, window

Since Ubuntu 18.04 I'm more or less forced to use Gnome Shell (also given the discontinuation of Unity...)
Wine apps used to run fine in Unity 7 (7.5.0). They still run fine in Gnome Shell (3.28.3) *except* they are not recognized as windows. Which means: I can click and interact with everything *inside* the app (including menus) but not the window itself (I can't drag the title bar, can't user <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKey</kbd> to move the window).

The Gnome Shell title bar never recognizes the launched wine app and will show nothing in the place where the application title should be. I also can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> -  the Wine app always stays on top (and can be clicked inside) while the active window (as shown in the Gnome Shell title bar) changes.

I assume this isn't a bug since I can't imagine that Wine is broken/unusable for *all* Gnome Shell users, so: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a console, type `winecfg` then enter. This will open the configuration tool of wine. (I think that if you type "wine config" into gnome search bar, you might also get a "Configure wine" app, it's the same).

Under "graphics", make sure "**Allow the window manager to decorate the window**" and "**Allow the window manager to control the window**" are checked.
[image: Screenshot of graphics config tab of winecfg]

You have to do that for all wineprefix you use.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How could this be unchecked? And why do these options even exist?

Comment: I don't know if it still applies, but some games or fullscreen apps did not play very nice with the linux window manager.

Comment: Also, sometimes you might want to prevent your window manager to decorate the window. It is useful for applications that re-implements their own bar and buttons for a better look&feel (that's the intention at least). If you keep this checked, you'd have 2 application topbar: the skinned one, and on top the native linux one. Ugly :-)

Comment: As for the "how could this be unchecked", I have no idea really.

Comment: Mine are checked and I still have this problem... that's unfortunate... I can't find an answer anywhere.